# Use a desktop application outside of corp network

Tags: c#, windows-authentication

I have a WPF desktop application that is deployed and it works fine within the corp network.

Now we have a new requirement that the application is to be used outside of the corp network. The application uses Windows authentication to connect to the database and I use entity framework to connect to SQL server. I cannot use SQL authentication as the SQL server is in Windows authentication and it cannot be changed.

How can I make this work outside of the corp network?

Comment: They can't access the corporate network using  VPN?

Comment: If the non-corp network users are on a domain, you could federate their domains in order for them to gain access. If they are not on a domain, you will need multiple authentication methods. Considering your user base is growing, you may also want to start looking at a Service Oriented Architecture that can support future growth so not everyone is hitting the database directly.

Comment: +1 For not having computers outside the domain directly hitting the database. Have them access a webserver or some such thing then have the web server hit the DB. The web server can either impersonate the user's domain account or else have its own authentication scheme and then use a separate domain account that has been set up with the appropriate permissions for the web service to hit the DB.

Comment: @Mick No they cannot be given any kind of access to the corporate network

Comment: Odd requirements.  If they're using Windows Authentication, that implies they have rights to access the corporate network.

Comment: If they can't vpn into the corporate network you're going to be forced to make major architectural changes.  Rewritting the application as a web site.  Or splitting the application, moving the business layer behind Web API and consume the Web API form the WPF application.